# src tag using javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am using  HTML and JavaScript

```
var image="a.png";
<img src="+image+">
```

output is coming

```
<img src="+image+">
```

But expected output is

```
<img src="a.png">
```

Any idea how to achieve this

Comment: Can you share the whole script?

Comment: Well if you are not creating whole `img` tag in JS, it won't help.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to have some default img in your HTML body first for example:

```
<img id="my_id" src="default.png"/>
```

Then you can use jQuery or javascript directly to get the element by ID and set the src. For example in jquery you can do this:

```
$("#my_id").attr("src",image);
```

Or in plain javascript

```
document.getElementById("my_id").src = image;
```